# Is there a way to get file metadata from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, metadata

Is there a way to get a file's metadata from the command line in Windows XP and above?

Particularly, I'm interested in getting the information one might normally see on the "Details" tab of a file's "Properties" dialog in Windows 7.  ("Version" tab in XP.)  Screenshots of both are below, to give an idea of what I'm after.

If possible, I'd rather do this through `cmd.exe` or something else that comes standard with Windows XP SP3 and above.  If this is not possible, my preferred alternatives would be:

- PowerShell
- A SysInternals utility
- A Nirsoft utility
- Some other tool from a similarly reputable and well-recognized developer.

Windows XP screenshot:
[image: Windows XP - Version tab in File Properties]

Windows 7 screenshot:
[image: Windows 7 - Details tab in File Properties]

Comment: You can install [`FILEVER`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913111) from the Windows CD.

Comment: @WilliamJackson - That sounds like a possible answer. Mind posting it as one, and maybe fleshing it out a bit with some of the info that's in that KB article?  Also, could you suggest something for higher versions of Windows?  I understand from some searching that `FILEVER` is not included on those CDs, and so may not be a supported tool for those versions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [WMIC.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get most of the way there:

```
C:\>wmic datafile where Name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" get Manufacturer,Name,Version
Manufacturer           Name                         Version
Microsoft Corporation  c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe  6.1.7601.17514
```

Note the escaping of the backslashes `\` in the path (it does not work otherwise).

Comment: extension of this method to compare versions in a batch: http://superuser.com/a/904535/131936

Comment: You can get just about any OS info you need for most operations through WMI but it comes with a _major_ caveat; it's quite slow. Orders of magnitude slower than most of the more direct routes. That said, it does work for a _lot_ of queries and monitoring.

Comment: This give an error: `wmic : Unexpected switch at this level.` on W81, same for Iszi soulution.

Comment: `wmic datafile get` doesnt really offer most of the info im looking for. any other way to do this? for instance, any way to get the `company`, `authors`, `legal trademark`, `copyright`, etc, fields of a given file?

Comment: This seems to no longer be working.  Just says "`ERROR:
Description = Invalid query`"

Comment: Can verify this command is not working for me on Windows 8. `ERROR: Description = Invalid query`

Comment: The solution to make it work on Windows 10 is to get rid of `where Name=`, as in `wmic datafile "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe" get Manufacturer,Name,Version`

Comment: Is there a way to make this work to get the file description? `wmic datafile where Name="C:\\windows\\explorer.exe" get Description` results in `C:\windows\explorer.exe` instead of `Windows Explorer` as it's shown in the Properties dialog.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be pulled with a combination of [dsofile.dll](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8422) (not needed if you have Office installed) and [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or any .NET language.

I also found a [powershell](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c3d0ea6c-64a1-4716-a262-bcd71c9925fc) method, but I haven't been able to test it.

I wrote up a little script with autoit that still needs some tweaking. I am on Vista and I can't get the few dsofile.dll calls to function as I would expect, though it still provides some output that you might be interested in. I'll work on this more in the morning when I have access to an XP and win7 VM. Note that you need to change the path in the dll functions to wherever you install dsofile.dll.

```
#include <file.au3>
Dim $file, $objFile, $Path, $encoding, $attrib, $attributes, $dt, $stamp, $szDrive, $szDir, $szFName, $szExt

If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then
    ConsoleWrite("You must specify a file")
Else
    $file = $CmdLine[1]
    If FileExists($file) Then
        _DLLstartup()
        $objFile = ObjCreate("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
        If Not IsObj($objFile) Then Exit
        $objFile.Open(FileGetLongName($file))
        $Path = _PathSplit($file, $szDrive, $szDir, $szFName, $szExt)
        ConsoleWrite("Filename: " & $Path[3] & $Path[4] & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Size: " & FileGetSize($file) & " bytes" & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Version: " & FileGetVersion($file) & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Company: " & $objFile.SummaryProperties.Company & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Author: " & $objFile.SummaryProperties.Author & @CRLF)
        $encoding = FileGetEncoding($file)
            Select
            Case $encoding = 0
                $encoding = "ANSI"
            Case $encoding = 32
                $encoding = "UTF16 Little Endian"
            Case $encoding = 64
                $encoding = "UTF16 Big Endian"
            Case $encoding = 128
                $encoding = "UTF8 (with BOM)"
            Case $encoding = 256
                $encoding = "UTF8 (without BOM)"
            EndSelect
        ConsoleWrite("Encoding: " & $encoding & @CRLF)
        $attrib = FileGetAttrib($file)
        $attributes = ""
            If StringInStr($attrib, "R") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " READONLY"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "A") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " ARCHIVE"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "S") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " SYSTEM"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "H") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " HIDDEN"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "N") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " NORMAL"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "D") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " DIRECTORY"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "O") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " OFFLINE"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "C") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " COMPRESSED"
            EndIf
            If StringInStr($attrib, "T") <> 0 Then
                $attributes = $attributes & " TEMPORARY"
            EndIf
        ConsoleWrite("Attributes:" & $attributes & @CRLF)
        $dt = FileGetTime($file, 1)
        $stamp = $dt[0] & "-" & $dt[1] & "-" & $dt[2] & " " & $dt[3] & ":" & $dt[4] & ":" & $dt[5]
        ConsoleWrite("Created: " & $stamp & @CRLF)
        $dt = FileGetTime($file, 0)
        $stamp = $dt[0] & "-" & $dt[1] & "-" & $dt[2] & " " & $dt[3] & ":" & $dt[4] & ":" & $dt[5]
        ConsoleWrite("Accessed: " & $stamp & @CRLF)
        $dt = FileGetTime($file, 2)
        $stamp = $dt[0] & "-" & $dt[1] & "-" & $dt[2] & " " & $dt[3] & ":" & $dt[4] & ":" & $dt[5]
        ConsoleWrite("Modified: " & $stamp & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Short Name: " & FileGetShortName($file, 1) & @CRLF)
        ConsoleWrite("Long Name: " & FileGetLongName($file, 1))
        $objFile.Close
        _DLLshutdown()
    Else
        ConsoleWrite("Can't find file")
    EndIf
EndIf

Func _DLLstartup($DLLpath = '')  ;borrowed from Andrew Goulart
    If $DLLpath = Default Or $DLLpath = '' Then $DLLpath = "C:\DsoFile\dsofile.dll";@ScriptDir & '\dsofile.dll'
    ShellExecuteWait('regsvr32', '/s /i ' & $DLLpath, @WindowsDir, 'open', @SW_HIDE)
EndFunc

Func _DLLshutdown($DLLpath = '') ;borrowed from Andrew Goulart
    If $DLLpath = Default Or $DLLpath = '' Then $DLLpath = "C:\DsoFile\dsofile.dll";@ScriptDir & '\dsofile.dll'
    ShellExecuteWait('regsvr32', ' /s /u ' & $DLLpath, @WindowsDir, 'open', @SW_HIDE)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @bobbymcr 's answer above (which I found very helpful, thank you!); you can simplify the command and broaden the results by using the `LIST BRIEF` or `LIST FULL` options.

Check `> wmic datafile list /?` for more details.

This solution helped me:
`> wmic datafile "c:\\path\\to\\file.exe" list full`

**Note:** As mentioned by @bobbymcr, remember to escape the `\`, else it won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry this isn't working for you.  I've just tried it again and it does work.  Win7, admin rights.  Full file path, and escaped '\'.

Answer (score 2):

To get all metadata:

```
wmic datafile where name="c:\\path\\to\\file.ext"
```

To view neatly in separate lines:

```
wmic datafile where name="c:\\path\\to\\file.ext" get /value
```