# Get Extended Properties of a file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, properties

What's the fastest way to output the **'Title'** property of all files in a directory in Windows 7? I tried `dir` in command line but that only prints the *filename*, not the **Title** found in the extended properties. Is there a fast way of iterating a directory (preferably via commandline or batch)?

Comment: Probably can be done using PowerShell in Windows7, but have no clue how to get it done though....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714415(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sounds similar to a question I had awhile ago.  I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Here.  See if you can adapt some of the answers from this question to help:  http://superuser.com/questions/363278/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-metadata-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link where James O'Neill creates a powershell script to get at any of the extended properties.  He uses it to get at all the camera properties stored in a file, but Title is one of them.

[Borrowing from Windows Explorer in PowerShell part 2: extended properties](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2008/12/09/borrowing-from-windows-explorer-in-powershell-part-2-extended-properties.aspx)

The function:

```
    function Get-ext 

{param ($attributes, $Path=(pwd).path)
 $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
 $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($path)
 0..266 | Foreach-object -begin {$Columns=@{} } -process {$Columns.add($objFolder.getDetailsOf($Null, $_),$_)}
 foreach ($file in $objFolder.items())  {          $attributes | forEach -begin  {$fileObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Object } `

                               -process {Add-Member -inputObject $fileObj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ `                                                                 -Value ($objFolder.GetDetailsOf($file , $Columns[$_]) )}  `
                                -end { $fileObj} }

}
```

Calling the function:

```
Get-ext "name","Title","Tags","f-stop","Exposure Time","ISO Speed" | ft *
```

---

original url link left in for completeness

<strike>http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2008/12/09/borrowing-from-windows-explorer-in-powershell-part-2-extended-properties.aspx</strike>

Comment: You could easily copy the relevant content into your post. The problem with link only answers is links go bad! Copying content is absolutely fine providing it is cited (as it is). If you copy the content over, I'll remove my -1

Comment: Unfortunately the link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @MattV the link was moved to an archive, I have updated the link and kept the original link for reference and searching.  And  the code is now included.