# How can I modify executable metadata through the command line?

Tags: command-line, file-attributes

How can I modify these fields on an executable? I've [found](https://superuser.com/questions/363278/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-metadata-from-the-command-line) [a few](https://superuser.com/questions/891742/how-can-i-compare-the-versions-of-two-executables-from-the-command-line/904535#904535) questions here on how to *get* these fields but none on how to set them. In addition, I need to be able to do this through a batch file or command line or something, as it will be part of an automated process.

[image]

Specifically, I need to change the "File description", "Product name", and "Copyright" fields.

If it helps, the file is an executable of a game built through Unity, and I have access to the source. I couldn't find any way to set these fields through Unity.

I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886561/how-can-i-edit-an-exes-resources-file-description-icon-etc-using-a-command) on Stack Overflow, which recommends using [this tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) from CodeProject. This tool does everything I needed to do!