# Is there a way to query file details from a Windows CMD prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to query the file details from a Windows CMD prompt? Looking for a way to query information from the "Details" tab of the file properties...

[image]

I can query other information from within this Details tab (like version) using WMIC, but the "Product name" seems to be elusive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question>>>https://superuser.com/questions/363278/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-metadata-from-the-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell cmdlet `Get-ItemProperty` would list the properties you're looking for.

The Specific property you're looking for is the `VersionInfo` Property.

Here an example where I ran it on an exe file (you also need `| fl *` to see everything):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-itemproperty "C:\Path\PDFX4.exe" | fl *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro\PDFX4.exe
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro
PSChildName       : PDFX4.exe
PSDrive           : Z
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro\PDFX4.exe
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:      4.188.188.0
                    FileDescription:  PDF-XChange 4 Pro
                    Product:          PDF-XChange 4 Pro
                    ProductVersion:   4.188.188.0
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:         Sprachneutral

BaseName          : PDFX4
Target            :
LinkType          :
Name              : PDFX4.exe
Length            : 29597392
DirectoryName     : Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro
Directory         : Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : Z:\Software\i-p\PDF-XChange Pro\PDFX4 pro\PDFX4.exe
Extension         : .exe
CreationTime      : 25.05.2020 23:19:32
CreationTimeUtc   : 25.05.2020 21:19:32
LastAccessTime    : 25.05.2020 23:19:32
LastAccessTimeUtc : 25.05.2020 21:19:32
LastWriteTime     : 02.12.2010 08:32:41
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 02.12.2010 07:32:41
Attributes        : Archive
```

If you only want to see the VersionInfo you can use:

```
get-itemproperty "C:\Path\PDFX4.exe" | select VersionInfo | fl *
```

Comment: If one _really_ wants to run it from the Commandline: `powershell.exe (Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Path\File.exe').VersionInfo.ProductName` ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 isn't PowerShell also a Commandline :-)?

Comment: Shhh, don't tell anyone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With just Command, I do not think so.

But there definitely is a Powershell Cmdlet to do this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214905/get-attributes-listed-in-the-details-tab-with-powershell

> This script uses the Shell.Application object to get file metadata. It
> returns the metadata as a custom PowerShell object, and therefore can
> be sorted and otherwise processed. It is a bit slow because it checks
> all 266 possible fields for data for each file in the folder. I
> recommend that you store the results in a variable and then do your
> post processing of data after you have collected the objects. See the
> Hey Scripting Guy blog article from Feb. 5, 2014 for more information
> about this function.

Here is a Microsoft background article.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

I would use Wmic from cmd:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\File\\Path\\Backslashes\\Doubled" get * /format:list
```

Or use `Shell.Application` in powershell:

```
$s=New-Object -com SHELL.application
$f=$s.namespace("FOLDER_PATH")
$f.getdetailsof($f.parsename("FILENAME_WITH _EXTENSION_NO_PATH"),NUMBER)
```