# Is there a way to get file description field from the file metadata using the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, metadata

I'm looking for a way to use the command line on windows 10 and 11 to read the `File description` field from the metadata of a file.

The value of many other fields can be get using [wmic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) as described in answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/363278/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-metadata-from-the-command-line).

But there seems to be no way to get the value displayed on `File description` using that method. For example, for the windows `explorer.exe`, the properties shown in Win11 might look like this

[image]

but all `wmic` displays is the full path to the file:

```
C:\>wmic datafile where Name="C:\\windows\\explorer.exe" get Description
Description
C:\windows\explorer.exe
```

Are there ways to get every field shown in the explorer.exe dialog and get the same value as shown there using the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Powershell's Get-Item to get the properties:

`(Get-Item C:\Windows\Explorer.exe).VersionInfo.FileDescription`

Result:
`Windows Explorer`

Comment: Accepting this for its terseness and because it's using now built-in functionality but it's a close one. I also like the exiftool solution and harrymc's for its added value and the reference.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a third party tool, exiftool can do the job:

exiftool -filedescription c:\windows\explorer.exe

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use PowerShell to access the metadata attributes of the file.

The following script which you may store in a `.ps1` file and execute
in a PowerShell session will get the file description:

```
$path = 'C:\windows\explorer.exe'
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 34)
```

Running this script will do this :

```
PS C:\Temp> .\test.ps1
Windows Explorer
```

If you wish to list all the possible attributes and their ids, replace
the last line of the above script with:

```
0..287 | Foreach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $_, $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_) }
```

and run it, for example, using the PowerShell command:

```
.\test.ps1 | Out-File C:\Temp\f.txt
```

This will give an output similar to:

```
0 = Name
1 = Size
2 = Item type
3 = Date modified
4 = Date created
5 = Date accessed
6 = Attributes
7 = Offline status
etc.
```

Reference :
[Enumerate file properties in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following cmdlet in Powershell:

```
(Get-Item C:\Windows\Explorer.exe).VersionInfo | select FileDescription

FileDescription
---------------
Windows Explorer
```